# How to get duration in weeks with Moment.js?

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I use `moment.js` to format durations in human readable format.
For example (`d` is a `Date` object):

```
moment(d).subtract("days", 3).from(d)  // returns "3 days ago"
```

Now I would like to get "2 weeks ago" but the code below returns the durations in days

```
moment(d).subtract("weeks", 2).from(d) // returns "14 days ago" i/o "2 weeks ago"
```

How can I get "2 weeks ago" with `moment.js`?

Answer (score 9):

You can do this pretty easily with a custom callback function.

```
moment.relativeTime.dd = function (number) {
    // round to the closest number of weeks
    var weeks = Math.round(number / 7);
    if (number < 7) {
        // if less than a week, use days
        return number + " days";
    } else {
        // pluralize weeks
        return weeks + " week" + (weeks === 1 ? "" : "s"); 
    }
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/timrwood/sWsXQ/

Answer (score 6):

#### Use the new `updateLocale()`.

Moment.js has been updated again so [the preferred method](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/customization/relative-time/) is the following:

```
moment.updateLocale('en', {

  relativeTime : {
    future: 'in %s',
    past:   '%s ago',
    s:      'a few seconds',
    m:      'a minute',
    mm:     '%d minutes',
    h:      'an hour',
    hh:     '%d hours',
    d:      'a day',
    dd:     function(number) {
              if (number < 7) {
                return number + ' days'; // Moment uses "d" when it's just 1 day.
              }
              else {
                var weeks = Math.round(number / 7);
                return weeks + ' ' + (weeks > 1 ? 'weeks' : 'week');
              }
            },
    M:      'a month',
    MM:     '%d months',
    y:      'a year',
    yy:     '%d years'
  }

});
```

Thanks to [@timrwood](https://stackoverflow.com/users/272034/timrwood) and [@gahen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2669979/gahen) for their answers.

I'm in the works to get Moment updated so that you can override just **a single** `relativeTime` object, like `dd`, instead of having to provide all of the objects.

The GitHub Issue is [here](https://github.com/moment/moment/issues/3137), so give it a thumbs up if you'd like to do something like this instead:

```
moment.updateLocale('en', {

  relativeTime : {
    dd: function(number) {
          if (number < 7) {
            return number + ' days'; // Moment uses "d" when it's just 1 day.
          }
          else {
            var weeks = Math.round(number / 7);
            return weeks + ' ' + (weeks > 1 ? 'weeks' : 'week');
          }
        }
  }

});
```

Answer (score 5):

I can't comment on the previous answer but I wanted to leave an updated answer (based on [timrwood](https://stackoverflow.com/users/272034/timrwood)'s)

```js
moment.locale('en', {
  relativeTime : {
    future: "in %s",
    past:   "%s ago",
    s:  "seconds",
    m:  "a minute",
    mm: "%d minutes",
    h:  "an hour",
    hh: "%d hours",
    d:  "a day",
    dd: function (number) {
      var weeks = Math.round(number / 7);
      if (number < 7) {
        // if less than a week, use days
        return number + " days";
      } else {
        // pluralize weeks
        return weeks + " week" + (weeks === 1 ? "" : "s"); 
      }
    },
    M:  "a month",
    MM: "%d months",
    y:  "a year",
    yy: "%d years"
  }
});

$window.moment.relativeTimeThreshold('d', 340); // if you want weeks instead of months, otherwise put a 28 or so.
```

Answer (score 2):

sharing and hoping still useful:

```
var aPastDate = moment().subtract(5,'months');
var now = moment();


moment.fn.durationInWeeks = function (fromDate, toDate) {

   var weeks =  toDate.diff( fromDate, 'weeks' );
   return weeks + ' weeks ago'; //your own format

}

moment().durationInWeeks(aPastDate,now);

//"21 weeks ago"
```

Answer (score 2):

improving on @vinjenzo's answer, when you need date diff in weeks, you will most likely encounter days returned:

```
var aPastDate = moment().subtract(5,'months');
var aPastDay = moment().subtract(6,'days');
var now = moment();

moment.fn.durationInWeeks = function(fromDate, toDate) {

    var days    = toDate.diff(fromDate, 'days');    
    var weeks   = toDate.diff(fromDate, 'weeks');

    if (weeks === 0) {
        return days + ' ' + (days > 1 ? 'days' : 'day');
    } else {
        return weeks + ' ' + (Math.round(days / 7) > 1 ? 'weeks' : 'week');
    }

}

moment().durationInWeeks(aPastDate,now); // 21 weeks
moment().durationInWeeks(aPastDay,now);  // 6 days
```

Answer (score 1):

The [documentation](http://momentjs.com/docs/) lists the rules for creating those strings (under "Humanize time from another moment"). While you can modify the strings by changing `moment.relativeTime`, this is limited to the text that is displayed around the number, i.e. you can't change days to weeks.

You'll have to extend `moment.js` or write some custom code to implement this functionality.