# Getting result from moment.js diff/from/fromNow in weeks instead of days

Tags: javascript, momentjs

Given this code:

```
var now = moment();
now.day("Tuesday");
var displayed_week_day = moment();
var one_week = moment.duration(1, 'weeks');
displayed_week_day.day("Tuesday");
displayed_week_day.add(one_week);
console.log(displayed_week_day.from(now));
displayed_week_day.add(one_week);
console.log(displayed_week_day.from(now));
```

The output is:

```
in 7 days
in 14 days
```

The docs would lead me to believe that this would output as "in 1 week" or "in 2 weeks". I don't see a way to pass an argument to this to make it do that.

There was an earlier stack question here: [How to get duration in weeks with Moment.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11448340/how-to-get-duration-in-weeks-with-moment-js) but this response is quite old and does not seem to apply to current versions of moment.js. Does anyone have thoughts on how to change the output format of this?

Answer (score 1):

Actually, in the docs it says that anywhere from 22 hours to 25 days is represented in terms of days.  (>=22 && < 36 hours rounds to a single day, >= 36 hours rounds to 2 days)

See the chart under the [Time from now](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/fromnow/) section.

The ability to customized these ranges has been requested and is an [open issue here](https://github.com/moment/moment/issues/892).

Comment: So there is a way to do this but you have to manually change the ranges in the moment.js code?

Comment: Yeah, you would have to replace the `relativeTime` function in your own copy of the source code

Comment: Not sure if you want to update your answer to show generally how/where to do that? If so I will mark your answer as accepted. Otherwise I can answer my own with that info. Thanks!