# Momen.js instagram like date format

Tags: javascript, momentjs

How to format date to some weeks ago with moment js relative time? For example, as of today
`moment("20150306", "YYYYMMDD").fromNow(true);` would return `a year`. But I'd like it return `52 weeks`, similar to instagram dates. 
Any tips for a custom function to convert months and years to weeks? Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get duration in weeks with Moment.js?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11448340/how-to-get-duration-in-weeks-with-moment-js)

Comment: Well I looked at the answers on that question, no selected answer nor any of them helped me. So I posted this one here and I got the answer. I don't see any problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `moment.duration().asWeeks` and the following:

```
var a = Math.round(moment.duration(moment("20150306", "YYYYMMDD").diff(moment())).asWeeks()) * -1;
alert(a + (a > 1 ? ' weeks ago' : ' week ago'));
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/xpzn08ut/)